# EditText inside list view android loses focus and data getting copied into another records

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, listviewitem, lost-focus

I am working on a custom `listView` which contains `editText` in every list item. 
My `listItem` is in `fragment`, and its activity has already `adjustResize` property which i can not change to adjustPan. Problem is when I click the edittext it is losing focus and even after two three clicks if it gains focus , then upon scrolling that value gets copied into another records and keyboard gets hanged. 
I am using

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

on my `listView`. Also i am using `ViewHolder` pattern in my adapter . Any tested links or working piece of code is really appreciated.

Comment: Data being copied into the wrong view sounds like a problem in your getView function

Comment: It might be due to viewholder pattern and its getting recycled, any idea about focus?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue dealing with RecyclerView with EditText's in the rows recently so this **might** help you.

When the keyboard comes up your list resizes and maybe the row that caused the keyboard to come up is not visible any more. You need to scroll to it and give it focus back.

How would you know that the keyboard is up? There is no elegant way, I do it by setting GlobalLayoutListener on the recyclerView, saving it's original size, and listening for a smaller size being reported. Search for "android keyboard listener" and you'll find some code.

1. When user taps on a EditText save the position of the row.
2. Listen for global layout changes to figure out that the keyboard is up.
3. Scroll to the row with the saved position.
4. Give the EditText focus. (probably in a posted Runnable to wait for the scroll to actually happen)

Comment: Can you share that piece of code? And moreover if the list doesn't scroll, even then it doesn't catches the focus. What is the workaround for focus?

Comment: I can't share it, it's not my property. Unfortunately I don't have the time to write the code. There is no specific workaround EditText.requestFocus() should do it, once the keyboard is up. I don't see why it would lose focus if it doesn't scroll off the screen though.